# how to display jquery Array key value pair ?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to display an array of key value pair, but couldn't code it properly.

```
 var result =new Array( {'id' : 1}, {'id' : 2} );

$.each($.parseJSON(result), function(k, v) {
    alert(k + ' is ' + v);
});
```

Here is the Fiddle links.

http://jsfiddle.net/27UFu/

Comment: what is the desired output - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FF2P6/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your code as below:

```
var result =[ {'id' : 1}, {'id' : 2} ];

$.each(result, function(k, v) {
    alert("id" + ' is ' + v.id);
});
```

---

According to your comments, here is the updated code:

```
var result =[ {'id' : 1}, {'id' : 2} ];

$.each(result, function(k, v) {
    for(var prop in v){
        if(v.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            alert(prop + ' is ' + v[prop]);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your code, But i need something different , Suppose if my array look like this means, how can i display the data.   var result =[ {'first_id' : 1}, {'second_id' : 2} ];   here i need to show both things, first_id and its value 1. how to print those two items.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var result =[ {'id' : 1}, {'id' : 2} ];

$.each(result, function(k, v) {
    for(var prop in v){
        alert(k + ' is ' + prop);
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/27UFu/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var result =new Array( {'id' : 1}, {'id' : 2} );
$.each(result, function(key, value){
    $.each(value, function(key, value){
        alert(key+' : '+value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Good answer, a explanation of what this code does would make it even better!